# How to gather the full config of a NixOS system?

Tags: nixos, nix

I read a bit about NixOS and tried it these days, because I got the impression that it would let me configure a Linux with just one file.

When I used it, I installed a bunch of packages with `nix-env`, so they didn't end up in the `configuration.nix`, but I could simply uninstall them later and add them to the `configuration.nix` by hand. I there something like `npm i -g <package>` that would install this globally so it would end up in the `configuration.nix` and could simply be copied to another machine.

Also, I installed stuff like `zsh` and `atom` and they have an entirely different approach to configuration and customization (bashscript, javascript, less, etc).

**Is there a way for Nix/NixOS to track the package-specific config too?**

Does it already happen and I don't see it? Like the nix expression of the package knows where the package will store its config etc.

I mean, it's nice that I can add these packages to the main config and when using it at another PC I get the same software installed, but I still see myself writing rather much configs for the installed packages too.

Answer (score 9):

1. If you want packages installed through `configuration.nix`, then the easiest way to accomplish that is to add them to the `environment.systemPackages` attribute. Packages listed in there will be available automatically to all users on the machine. As far as I know, there is no shell command available to automate the maintenance of that attribute, though. The only way to manage that list is by editing `configuration.nix` and manually adding the packages you'd like to have installed.
2. Nix does *not* manage package-specific configuration files. As you probably know, NixOS provides such a mechanism for files in `/etc`, but a similar mechanism to manage config files in `$HOME` etc. does not exist. The PR https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/9250 on Github contains a concrete proposal to add this capability to Nix, but it hasn't been merged yet because it requires some changes that are controversial.

Comment: Yes I saw that PR after I posted this. Seems like even if it is merged, an Atom config is still JavaScript and not a Nix Expression. So versioning this myself will probably always be the case.

Comment: In Nix world, it's usually done this way that Nix packages ("expressions") describing particular app *generate* the app-specific config files (.json, .ini, .rc, .xml, or whatever else) under the wraps, based on "pretty" config options which can be tweaked from *configuration.nix* (or *~/.nixpkgs/config.nix*). The options are usually exposed on "as needed" basis by package writers (if you learn Nix, you can try to do it yourself!); also, not all apps make it easy (one has to override default location of config file to point into auto-generated file in */nix/store/*).

Answer (score 2):

Nix does not currently offer ways of managing user specific configuration or language specific package managers. AFAICT that's because it is a very complex and opinionated territory compared to generating configs for sshd etc.

There are however Nix-based projects providing solution to at least some parts of your question. For managing user configuration (zsh etc.), have a look at [home manager](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager).